# How to dynamically create a text box with runat=server in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create a textbox dynamically. I can successfully create it via the below code:

```
var parentTable = $('<table border="0" class="table table-bordered" width="100%" id="searchInformation"/>');
var tr = $("<tr class='searchEntitydata'/>");
var tr2 = $("<tr class='searchEntitydata1'/>");

tr.append("<td id='HQNametd'>  <label ID='hqName'>HQ Name</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearch' placeholder='Search HeadQuarter'> </td>");
tr.append("<td id='HQIDtd'>  <label ID='hqId'>HQ ID</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearchHQId' placeholder='Search ID'> </td>");
tr.append("<td id='BranchNametd'>  <label ID='BranchName'>Branch Name</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearchBranchName' placeholder='Search Branch Name'> </td>");
tr.append("<td id='BranchIdtd'>  <label ID='BranchId'>Branch Id</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearchBranchId' placeholder='Search Branch ID'> </td>");

tr2.append("<td id='Citytd'>  <label ID='City'>City</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearchBranchId' placeholder='Search Branch ID'> </td>");
tr2.append("<td id='Statetd'>  <label ID='State'>State</label>  <input type='textBox' id='textboxSearchBranchId' placeholder='Search Branch ID'> </td>");

parentTable.append(tr);
parentTable.append(tr2);
$('#confirmSearch').append(parentTable);
```

However, when I change the textbox type from `input type=textBox` 
to `asp:TextBox` for using `runat='server'`, I get an error.

Is there any way via which I can dynamically create a textbox with `runat=server`?

Comment: Do you need to do it on client-side? Is server-side solution OK?

Comment: @VladStryapko: Not just *okay*, but presumably necessary.

Comment: You cannot do that on clientside, only serverside

Comment: The "server" in "runat=server" is exactly that: Server-side. Your jQuery code runs client-side. You can't create a server-side control client-side. You can create a text box, and send its contents to the server, but it won't be a server control.

Comment: I want to send the content of a textbox to my code behind file. but I am not able to do that.

Comment: Use an asp.net ajax update panel and do it on server side if you use web forms.

Comment: Please let me know the answer convinced you or not

Answer (score 1):

**NO** you cannot add asp-runat="server" tag from jQuery or any client side script. Rather use following to generate textbox dynamically from server side, encapsulate your code within ajax control toolkit update panel.

**C#: (On click or page load or whatever server side event)**

```
TextBox tbOne = new TextBox();
Label lblOne = new Label();
lblOne.ID = "lblId";
lblOne.Text = "My label";
lblOne.Width = 200;

tbOne.ID = "tbId";
tbOne.Text = "xyz";
pnl.Controls.Add(lblOne);
pnl.Controls.Add(tbOne);
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl"Width="100%" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```